# WIN7 Keyboard hook stops working in another user account?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, keyboard-hook

I created my own parental control app using C# to monitor my kids activity. It logs all the keyboard input and screens in the background silently, with the only gui of taskbar icon. So far, I just let it run in my admin account and everybody share the same account and it works fine. The problem is that as kids grow up, they found a way to kill it from the task manager. So, I need to use a more sophisticated way to protect my app. I thought I could solve this problem easily by creating a separate standard account for each kid and I can setup my app to run as an admin to monitor all their activities. However, I faced a lot of issues.

1. The keyboard hooks seem to stop working once I switched to a different user account. Is it true? I thought it's global hook - is it just global within the user account?
2. The screen capturing doesn't work on another user account either. This is my code and

it failed at g.CopyFromScreen with error "the handle is invalid":

```
RECT rc = Win32.GetWindowRect();
using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height))
{
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(rc.Location, System.Drawing.Point.Empty, new System.Drawing.Size(rc.Width, rc.Height));
        string fileName = Settings.Instance.GetImageFileName();
        bitmap.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have bumped into the new Windows 7 features. Message filters and integrity levels. My question, though, how do you run the application? Within their account within the admin account? On what desktop? It will only work on the same desktop. Did you fix the desktop and window station ACL to grant access to the credentials as which your program runs?

Comment: Actually, I tried different ways to run the program (e.g. from Windows Service, or through Scheduled Tasks), but couldn't get it work. I'm not familiar with Win7's new features as you mentioned. For my testing, I simply started the program from my admin account, then switched to kid's account as standard user.

Comment: that won't work. Service also won't work (since about Vista due to the session separation restrictions). You have to run the process within the same desktop/winsta as the shell of the account that you want to monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the kids aren't administrators, you can run the program under their accounts and deny access to the process.

For example (tested):

```
static void SetAcl() {
    var sd = new RawSecurityDescriptor(ControlFlags.None,
        new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null),
        null, null, new RawAcl(2, 0));

    sd.SetFlags(ControlFlags.DiscretionaryAclPresent | ControlFlags.DiscretionaryAclDefaulted);
    var rawSd = new byte[sd.BinaryLength];

    sd.GetBinaryForm(rawSd, 0);
    if (!NativeMethods.SetKernelObjectSecurity(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, SecurityInfos.DiscretionaryAcl, rawSd))
        throw new Win32Exception();
}

static class NativeMethods {
    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetKernelObjectSecurity(IntPtr target, SecurityInfos info, byte[] descriptor);
}
```

Comment: It's not so much tied to a particular group as it is to privileges, though.

Comment: Hi Slaks: Thanks a million. This is exactly what I want, I believe. But could you please elaborate a little bit more on how to use it? Who is going to call SetAcl()?

Comment: Call in in your program, and run under the limited user.

Comment: +1 from me. Also, make sure that you don't have any windows that would accept messages from other processes. There are no ACLs on windows, which is the reason why this could be a loophole.

Comment: I just tried it. In the installer, there is an option "Launch automatically when Windows starts up" > "For all users". After installion with this option, the program started automatically after reboot. However, in the standard user account, this program shows up in the task manager as my "admin" user. I guess, because of that, I cannot find the task bar icon for this app and the app doesn't seem to be working either. How do I workaround this limitation? I'd like to install once from my admin account and make it run for all accounts. Is it possible? How?

Comment: If you put it in All Users/Startup, it should run a separate copy for each account.

Comment: I'm using (the latest) inno-setup but couldn't make it work using "auto-launch for all users" option. But this is a separate issue I'll post separately. I'm accepting your answer for my original question. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: A related post can be find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530639/win7-inno-setup-how-to-make-a-program-auto-launch-for-all-users-run-under-ea

Comment: @SLaks: I run into a problem with this code. If I call this function, I get an exception "Access is denied" thrown by Process.MainModule. Any clue?

Comment: @SLaks, as you may have seen from my other post, I got this problem resolved. However, I got two other questions: 1. There seems to be a delay for this code to take effect. If I log in as a standard user and open task manager right away, I could still kill this process. However, if I wait for a while, I will not be able to kill it and get "Access is denied" . This function is called in MainWindow's constructor and it should take effect right away. so why this delay? or did I do something wrong? 2. Even if I logged in as admin, I also get "Access is denied" message when I try to kill it. Why?

Comment: @miliu: 1. Try putting it in App.cs.  2. You probably have UAC enabled.  Click Show processes from all users. BTW, I only tested this in XP.